# How to get the value of autocomplete text [using Horsey plugin]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Horsey plugin](https://github.com/bevacqua/horsey) to create an autocomplete for my text input. I'm using the key/value pairs (3rd example [here](https://bevacqua.github.io/horsey/)) and I want to POST the key value (id in my app), not the text value of my search.

```
horsey(document.querySelector('#search_field'), {
  source: [{ list: [
    { value: 'banana', text: 'Bananas from Amazon Rainforest' },
    { value: 'apple', text: 'Red apples from New Zealand' },
    { value: 'orange', text: 'Oranges from Moscow' },
    { value: 'lemon', text: 'Juicy lemons from the rich Amalfitan Coast' }
  ]}],
  getText: 'text',
  getValue: 'value'
});
```

So I understand I have to call getValue function from somewhere but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Does the field populate, once you select the value you want to populate the field with?

Comment: The field is populated (after pressing enter) with the text, but I don't see a way to get the key(value) :(

Comment: Does it exist in the element as a attribute or html?

Comment: Using inspect element I don't see any attribute added, so I assume it is html text. 
On a side note, from the docs, it says: horsey(element, options) returns a small API into the horsey autocomplete list instance. 
I guess it is this instance (returned from horsey()) that I have to apply the getValue method. I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Horsey binds to the element `('#search_field')` so the selected value would exist in this element this may sound trivial but did you try something like this  `$( "#target" ).change(function() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
});` Would you be able to add the content of the element after it has a populated value to the question?

Comment: I don't think I could access it that way. Also innerHTML is the text, even if that works I would get the 'text' and not the 'value' that I'm looking for..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **predictNextSearch(info)** that runs when a tag is inserted.

```
horsey(document.querySelector('#search_field'), {
  source: [{ list: [
    { value: 'banana', text: 'Bananas from Amazon Rainforest' },
    { value: 'apple', text: 'Red apples from New Zealand' },
    { value: 'orange', text: 'Oranges from Moscow' },
    { value: 'lemon', text: 'Juicy lemons from the rich Amalfitan Coast' }
  ]}],
  getText: 'text',
  getValue: 'value',
  predictNextSearch(info) {
        //get the suggestion selected by the user
        console.log(info.selection.value);
  }
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, now I can set the value attribute of my input field using predicNextSearch and it seems like a good solution. Thanks again!